# V8.NET trouble when building 3rd party tools

Tags: git, svn, v8, gyp, v8.net

I'm trying to install V8.NET https://v8dotnet.codeplex.com/.

It provides a program which downloads V8 and some 3rd party tools( gyp,...).

Prerequisites are installed git and subversion, and added to path. I have done both.

When trying to download 3rd party tools, I get

```
'build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
*** THE PREVIOUS STEP FAILED ***
```

I suppose I don't have this program or batch file installed or added to PATH, but I can't figure out which program is "build" as I cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In V8.Update.cmd there is a line

```
echo Downloading GYP ...
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp 
build/gyp  >getGYP.log
```

(line 56), as you can see, there is build/gyp in new line, that's why windows recognizes this as command. Just delete new line and it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version out, which contains a brand new script.  Google has significantly changed how V8 builds, and now requires their Depot Tools to be installed.

Also, CodePlex is shut down, so the new updates are here: https://github.com/rjamesnw/v8dotnet